# 16.04 guest on 16.04 host - "VBoxClient: Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service, rc=VERR_ACCESS_DENIED"

Tags: 16.04, apt, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS amd64 host with Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.1.30-118389~Ubuntu~xenial from [their repository](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian).

I have created Ubuntu 16.04 LTS amd64 guest in VBox. Installed all updates here with aptitude. Also I installed `virtualbox-guest-x11` (version 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 from multiverse repository) to guest.

After logging in to the VM I get the following notification:
[image: virtualbox error notification]

Why this happen?
Should I install the same version (5.1.30) of guest additions as host VirtualBox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How I got it working for me:

My setup:

- VirtualBox 6.0.4
- Host machine - Ubuntu 18.04
- Guest machine in virtualbox - Kali 2019.1 kernel version 4.19.0

Install needed packages with apt on GUEST machine

```
apt-get install build-essential virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

After this, run:

```
VBoxClient --clipboard
```

Also, make sure that you have enabled Shared Clipboard from Settings>General>Advanced on the HOST machine.

Now it should be working :)

Comment: NOTE: On VirtualBox 6.1, `--clipboard` has changed to `--clipboard-mode`

Comment: Thanks. It sent me in the right direction. In my case however, because I install the guest additions via the Virtualbox provided  disk, I did not need the `virtualbox-*` packages + I needed to do `sudo VBoxClient --clipboard`, otherwise I still got the permission denied errors.